# I need to close the popup message in component.ts in angular4

Tags: javascript, angular

In component.html i have a popup message currently the opening and closing functionality is in html but i need the close functionality in a method

```
   <ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
         <div class="modal-header">

          <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" 
            (click)="d('Cross click')">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>

             <h4>Cinema Operator</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                <li class="nav-item"> Import from your Excel </li>
                 </div>
                   <div class="modal-footer">

             <input type="file" accept=".xlsx" class="btn btn-
                 success"(change)="onFileChange($event)">

                <button type="file" class="btn dark btn-outline" 
                (click)="c('Close click');uploadfile()">Upload</button>
                              </div>
                        </ng-template> 
    ----------------------------------------------------
 <button class="btn btn-default" *ngIf="message" (click)="open(content)">Add New Operator</button>
```

open(content) will open the popup message and c('Close click') will close the popup message in Component.html but i need this close functionality in uploadfile() method 
Please help me this this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need is to pass the reference to the function ,

**Template Side :**

Change :

```
(click)="c('Close click');uploadfile()"
```

to

```
(click)="uploadfile(c)"
```

**Component Side :**

```
uploadfile(c){
    ... // your code
    c('Close click');
}
```